# How to achieve Base64 URL safe encoding for binary hash string in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, encoding, hash, binary, base64

I am getting the “input” from the server in “Base64-encoded” form [as shown in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHxyc.png).

1. I need to decode it into its original form of Binary string .i.e `original = base64_decode(input)` .
2. concatenate i.e `to_be_hash =password (known value) + input`.
3. Hash the concatenated string using SHA-256. i.e `binary_hash_str =sha256(to_be_hash)`.

I need Base64 URL-safe encode the binary hash string above to make it suitable for HTTP requests.

`final_hash = base64_url_safe_encode(binary_hash_str)`

I am using powershell for this. Can someone guide me how to progress please.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you would like to send a base64 string as a argument in a url?  You can escape the characters that are not acceptable in a url using `[uri]::EscapeDataString()`

```
$text = "some text!!"
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($text)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$urlSafeString = [uri]::EscapeDataString($base64)

"Base64        : " + $base64
"urlSafeString : " + $urlSafeString

Base64        : cwBvAG0AZQAgAHQAZQB4AHQAIQAhAA==
urlSafeString : cwBvAG0AZQAgAHQAZQB4AHQAIQAhAA%3D%3D
```

Comment: To avoid the escaping, most web apps expect `-` instead of `=` in Base64 strings.

Comment: It seems this might not be a consideration here, but the `+` and `/` can be undesirable in the base64 alphabet and for those, the RFC has an alternative alphabet: [RFC4648](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-5) -- some environments, such as Java, actually support this explicitly - I'm hoping to find a way to do it in PowerShell but so far have only found doing replacement manually afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this is shown here: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Posh-ACME/2.0.1/Content/Private%5CConvertTo-Base64Url.ps1

Base64Url-encode is not the same as Base64-encode + Url-encode.